# Matrix conditions to make it positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Let us assume that M is a positive-definite matrix of size $n \times n$. What are the conditions on $L$ of size $m \times n$, such that

$$ Q = LML'$$

is also positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- A matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if there exists a matrix $B$ for which $A = BB'$.
- A positive semidefinite matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if for column vectors $x$, $x'Ax = 0$ implies that $x = 0$.

Comment: From your first hint, this means that there exists a matrix $B$ such that $M=BB′$. Thus, we can write: $Q=LML′=(LB)(B′L')=YY'$ which again must be positive semi-defnite since $Q$ can be written as  $YY'$. So this means, there are no conditions on $L$ needed. Correct?

Comment: @Selos There are no conditions on $L$ required to ensure that $Q$ is positive **semi**definite. However, there is a condition required to ensure that $Q$ is positive definite.

Comment: Actually, it is enough for me that Q is positive semidefinite. But what I don't understand is, why is $Y=LB$ invertible in my case?

Comment: @Selos We have no reason to believe that $LB$ is invertible without further assumptions

Comment: But why are then no conditions on $L$ required such that Q is positive semidefnite?

Comment: @Selos Because every matrix of the form $Q = PP'$ is positive semidefinite. In this case, we have $Q = PP'$ with $P = LB$.